# Spring Batch: How do I use placeholders in step listeners?

Tags: java, spring-batch

```
<beans>
<batch:job id="job1" restartable="false">
  <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
    <batch:tasklet>
      <batch:chunk reader="readerA" writer="writerA" commit-interval="1" />
    </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>
  <batch:step id="step2">
    <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet1"/>
  </batch:step>
  <batch:listeners>
    <batch:listener ref="listenerA" />
  </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>

<bean id="listenerA" class="com.example.ListenerA" scope="step">
  <property name="archiveDate" value="#{jobParameters['jobRunDate']}" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Why does the above give me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context available while replacing placeholders.
```

What would be the best way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you wanted a step listener, and not a job listener.  The step scope is out of scope where you've defined your listener, so scope step is unavailable - if it was a job listener, you wouldn't need the placeholders because you could obtain the variables from the current JobExecution.

If you instead altered your configuration like so (assuming this is a step listener and not a job listener):

```
<batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
<batch:tasklet>
  <batch:chunk reader="readerA" writer="writerA" commit-interval="1" />
  <batch:listeners>
      <batch:listener ref="listenerA" />
 </batch:listeners>
</batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

I believe that would give you a proper step listener for the "step1" step - similar configuration if you wanted a listener for the second step.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a job listener.

Comment: Job Execution Listeners contain the following methods: void beforeJob(JobExecution execution) and void afterJob(JobExecution execution).  As I said in my answer, if it was a job listener, you wouldn't need the placeholders - in beforeJob simply use execution.getJobInstance().getJobParameters().getDate("jobRunDate"); (assuming it's a date, if not, use the appropriate getter for the value).

Comment: Doesn't this seem to violate the idea of configuring via the xml?

Comment: How so?  You place a step listener to listen to the step, and the job listener in one place because it listens to the job, not the step.  Nothing prevents you from having the same step listener listen to all steps as long as you copy and paste it for each step definition.  What you want is syntatic sugar, to be able to place a single step listener to listen to all steps.  That's certainly a valid case, and perhaps you should log an enhancement request so that it is implemented, but it doesn't break functionality to not have this.

Comment: No, why can I set job scoped parameters via jobParameters['blah'] in a step scoped object, but not in a job scoped object?

Comment: As far as I know there's no "job" scope provided in Spring batch - only a "step" scope.  With the JobListener you can access any parameters you need via the callbacks.

Comment: I think my confusion stems from the fact that this is a job being run by a job being run by a job, so the job scope would be a little muddy in the first place.  Thanks for being patient with my questions!